# Sitecore Workflow Auto "Smart" Publish

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

Using Sitecore 7.2:

Is there a way to change the Workflow Auto Publish to run a `Smart publish` rather than a `Republish`?

According to https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/reinnovations/posts/2014/03/auto-publish-workflow-action-updates.aspx there are 6 parameters that can be added (deep, related, targets, alllanguages, languages, itemlanguage), but I'm not finding any mention of changing the publish type.

EDIT: Since it's been suggested this top be closed because it's not programming, some additional details may be in order...

I had already viewed the decompiled `Sitecore.Workflows.Simple.PublishAction, Sitecore.Kernel` code (the default behavior of the Auto Publish) to find the parameters specified in the link above are the only parameters. So my understanding (unless I missed something) is a custom action is needed.

It seems odd to me that you can specify deep and related, but can't specify a "smart" publish, so my hope is that someone has already documented this so I don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a web app rather than programming

Comment: This is on-topic as Sitecore implementations always require custom development in some capacity.

Comment: Short answer: No, not in the default simple workflow. Long answer: Yes, but you have to create a custom PublishAction to do it. I'll knock up an answer if you need.

Answer (score 0):

The PublishAction is intended to trigger only for the item in context (i.e. the item approved in workflow). In general, smart vs. republish does not have much difference at a single item level. This action triggers a different mode not normally chosen by a user: SingleItem (neither smart nor republish)

The action will attempt to publish the context item, and any related items if you specify related to be true (which I recommend). However, this will then impact performance with a full republish running.

If you specify 'deep', the action will also publish children. I do not recommend having this enabled as an approval on the Home node of your site could theoretically trigger a publish of every item in the site.

Comment: "The reason you cannot specify Smart vs. Republish is because those particular options only apply for system-wide publishing" - that is not true. When you publish a single item, you have Smart vs. Republish (Incremental is a site-wide option only). I agree with 'deep=0' and 'related=1', but this still republishes and (worse yet) re-indexes a ridiculous number of items for 1 or 2 changes.

Comment: I must have been thinking of something else (or an older Sitecore version). Just double-checked in my 7.2 and you are correct that item publishing does give you smart vs. republish options.

I have updated my answer to remove the incorrect details. Thanks @thadmiller! 

I agree that the 'related' publishing forcing a republish of related is not performant.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the same solution, this worked for me:

```cs
public class PublishAction
{
    public void Process(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
    {
        Item dataItem = args.DataItem;
        Item innerItem = args.ProcessorItem.InnerItem;
        NameValueCollection parameters = WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(innerItem["parameters"]);
        bool deep = this.GetDeep(parameters, innerItem);
        bool related = this.GetRelated(parameters, innerItem);
        bool smart = this.GetSmart(parameters, innerItem);
        Database[] targets = Enumerable.ToArray<Database>(this.GetTargets(parameters, innerItem, dataItem));
        Language[] languages = Enumerable.ToArray<Language>(this.GetLanguages(parameters, innerItem, dataItem));
        if (!Settings.Publishing.Enabled || !Enumerable.Any<Database>((IEnumerable<Database>)targets) || !Enumerable.Any<Language>((IEnumerable<Language>)languages))
            return;
        PublishManager.PublishItem(dataItem, targets, languages, deep, smart, related);

    }
    private bool GetDeep(NameValueCollection parameters, Item actionItem)
    {
        return this.GetStringValue("deep", parameters, actionItem) == "1";
    }
    private bool GetRelated(NameValueCollection parameters, Item actionItem)
    {
        return this.GetStringValue("related", parameters, actionItem) == "1";
    }
    private bool GetSmart(NameValueCollection parameters, Item actionItem)
    {
        return this.GetStringValue("smart", parameters, actionItem) == "1";
    }
    private IEnumerable<Database> GetTargets(NameValueCollection parameters, Item actionItem, Item dataItem)
    {
        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
            IEnumerable<string> targetNames = this.GetEnumerableValue("targets", parameters, actionItem);
            if (!Enumerable.Any<string>(targetNames))
            {
                Item obj = dataItem.Database.Items["/sitecore/system/publishing targets"];
                if (obj != null)
                    targetNames = Enumerable.Where<string>(Enumerable.Select<Item, string>((IEnumerable<Item>)obj.Children, (Func<Item, string>)(child => child["Target database"])), (Func<string, bool>)(dbName => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbName)));
            }
            foreach (string name in targetNames)
            {
                Database database = Factory.GetDatabase(name, false);
                if (database != null)
                    yield return database;
                else
                    Log.Warn("Unknown database in PublishAction: " + name, (object)this);
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Language> GetLanguages(NameValueCollection parameters, Item actionItem, Item dataItem)
    {
        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
            IEnumerable<string> languageNames = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            bool allLanguages = this.GetStringValue("alllanguages", parameters, dataItem) == "1";
            if (allLanguages)
            {
                Item obj = dataItem.Database.Items["/sitecore/system/languages"];
                if (obj != null)
                    languageNames = Enumerable.Select<Item, string>(Enumerable.Where<Item>((IEnumerable<Item>)obj.Children, (Func<Item, bool>)(child => child.TemplateID == TemplateIDs.Language)), (Func<Item, string>)(child => child.Name));
            }
            else
            {
                languageNames = this.GetEnumerableValue("languages", parameters, actionItem);
                string current = this.GetStringValue("itemlanguage", parameters, dataItem);
                if ((current == "1" || current == null) && !Enumerable.Contains<string>(languageNames, dataItem.Language.Name))
                    yield return dataItem.Language;
            }
            foreach (string name in languageNames)
            {
                Language language = (Language)null;
                if (Language.TryParse(name, out language))
                    yield return language;
                else
                    Log.Warn("Unknown language in PublishAction: " + name, (object)this);
            }
        }
    }

    private string GetStringValue(string name, NameValueCollection parameters, Item actionItem)
    {
        string str1 = actionItem[name];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str1))
            return str1;
        string str2 = parameters[name];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str2))
            return str2;
        else
            return (string)null;
    }
    private IEnumerable<string> GetEnumerableValue(string name, NameValueCollection parameters, Item actionItem)
    {
        string str1 = actionItem[name];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str1))
        {
            return Enumerable.AsEnumerable<string>((IEnumerable<string>)str1.Split(new char[1] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        }
        else
        {
            string str2 = parameters[name];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str2))
                return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            return Enumerable.AsEnumerable<string>((IEnumerable<string>)str2.Split(new char[1] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        }
    }

}
```